# How to add function listener in google google.maps.Geocoder;

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

How to add function placeMarker into  google.maps.Geocoder;

In this code I click map and get lat,lng from map and it'll mark

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 9,
        center: {lat: 13.7245601, lng: 100.4930251}
    });
    map.addListener('click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}
```

here is my function place marker

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker == null) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    }

    $('#lat').val(location.lat())
    $('#lng').val(location.lng())
}
```

It's work but after I try to change into select province , district , google map will auto mark in map and how can I add function listener click too here is my code

```
function codeAddress(){
    var sub_dis = $('.sub_district_id').find(':selected').data('sub_dis');
    var distri = $('.district_id').find(':selected').data('district');
    var getProvince = $('.province_id').find(':selected').data('province');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12});
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;        
    geocoder.geocode({'address': getProvince+' '+distri+' '+sub_dis}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat())
    $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +
          status);
    }
  });

}
```

How can I add

```
map.addListener('click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
```

into codeAddress() function I try many way it still can't click after I find area.